# The inclusion map not always a group homomorphism $i: \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \to\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Consider the inclusion map $i: \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \to\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}, \, a \mapsto a$, Question: is this a group homomorphism?

$i$ certainly satisfies $i(a+b) = a + b = i(a) + i(b)$ but $i$ is not a well defined map: Since $\bar{0} = \bar{3}$, $i(\bar{0}) = \bar{0}$ but $i(\bar{3}) = \bar{3} \neq \bar{0}$.

So $i: \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \to\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, the inclusion map is not a group homomorphism in this case; this seemed surprising to me at first, does this look correct or am I missing something?

Edit: Instead of "inclusion" and "map", I was thinking "embedding" and "set map".

Comment: In your example the "inclusion map" is not a map.

Comment: Careful!! The map you are thinking of isn't really an inclusion at all. A typical element of $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ is a coset of $3 \Bbb Z$, while a typical element of $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ is a coset of $6 \Bbb Z$. These are different objects! Moreover, the "$+$" on the LHS isn't the same as "$+$" on the RHS. So you can define $i(\bar 0) = \bar 0$, $i(\bar 1) = \bar 1$, $i(\bar 2) = \bar 2$, but it's unclear that this is a homomorphism (and in fact it isn't: $i(\bar 1 + \bar 2) \ne i(\bar 1) + i(\bar 2)$). But you can also view the problem as a failure of well-definedness, it's a matter of perspective.

Comment: The "problem" here illustrates the pitfall of thinking that $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$... or even with putting bars over the characters :)

Comment: The correct "inclusion" is sending $1\pmod{3}$ to $2 \pmod{6}$. This generates an injective homomorphism.

Comment: It is not true that it is additive. The image of $1+2=0$ is $0$,  but the sum of the images is $3$. and if you want to say that "it is not well defined", then it makes no sense to say it is additive: if it is not a function, then it is not additive, for a prerquisite to being additive is being a function.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Good for pointing this out: not a function, hence one cannot talk of additivity, and it even fails here like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to think about homomorphisms $\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}\Z/3\Z\to G$ is to first look at a homomorphism $f\colon \Z\to G$. Then, by the [fundamental homomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms) there exists a group homomorphism $\bar f\colon \Z/3\Z\to  G$ given by $\bar f(a + 3\Z) = f(a)$ if and only if $3\Z \subseteq \ker f$. As the comments suggest, the problem is not that $\bar f$ could ever fail to be homomorphism, it can fail to be a map in the first place since you need to have $a + 3\Z = b + 3\Z \implies \bar f(a + 3\Z) = \bar f(b + 3\Z)$ which boils down precisely to the condition $3\Z\subseteq \ker f$.

You can convince yourself easily that all group homomorphisms $g\colon \Z/3\Z \to G$ are of this form just by considering $f\colon \Z \to G$ given by $f(a) = g(a+ 3\Z)$ and noting that $\bar f = g$.

Now, for your concrete example, you want to first consider a group homomorphism $f\colon \Z \to \Z/6\Z$ given by the canonical projection $f(a) = a + 6\Z$. Note that defining $f(a) = a$ is simply wrong since elements of $\Z$ and $\Z/6\Z$ are completely different things, even though we do sometimes abuse this notation, but then one needs to keep track of it mentally not to make mistakes. Kernel of $f$ is simply $6\Z$, so in order to $\bar f$ (given by $\bar f(a + 3\Z) = a + 6\Z$) be a well-defined map, we need to have $3\Z\subseteq 6\Z$, i.e. $3\mid x \implies 6\mid x$, which is not true. Therefore, $\bar f$ is not even a map.

To demonstrate this more concretely, note that $0 + 3\Z = 3 + 3\Z$ since $3\in 3\Z$. However, $$\bar f(0 + 3\Z) = f(0) = 0 + 6\Z \neq 3 + 6\Z = f(3) = \bar f(3+3\Z),$$ so $\bar f$ is not a function at all. We say that it's not well-defined since we tried to define it, but couldn't make it work.

---

Interestingly, there is a way to think of $\Z/3\Z$ as subgroup of $\Z/6\Z$ by considering $f\colon \Z\to \Z/6\Z$ given by $f(a) = 2a + 6\Z$. You can see that $\ker f = 3\Z$, so $\bar f(a + 3\Z) = 2a + 6\Z$ is not just a well-defined group homomorphism, it is a monomorphism, again by the fundamental homomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_map), if $A$ is a subset of $B$, then the inclusion map is defined by $\iota:A\rightarrow B$ where $\iota(x)=x$ for each $x\in A$. Therefore we can define inclusion map only when $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Note that $$\Bbb{Z} / n\Bbb{Z}=\{\bar{0},\bar{1},\dots, \overline{n-1}\}$$
where for each $\bar{g}\in \Bbb{Z} / n\Bbb{Z}$, $\bar{g}=\{g+nz:z\in \Bbb{Z}\}$.

In your question, $\Bbb{Z/3\Bbb{Z}}$ is not a subset of $\Bbb{Z/6\Bbb{Z}}$. In fact, all elements of $\Bbb{Z/3\Bbb{Z}}$ are not elements of $\Bbb{Z/6\Bbb{Z}}$. For example, $\bar{0}$ in $\Bbb{Z/3\Bbb{Z}}$ consists of all multiples of $3$, while in $\Bbb{Z/6\Bbb{Z}}$, $\bar{0}$ consists of all multiples of $6$. This means that $\bar{0}$ in $\Bbb{Z/3\Bbb{Z}}$ is not the same as $\bar{0}$ in $\Bbb{Z/6\Bbb{Z}}$.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo added. Thanks.